# How to upgrade a tcp connection to TLS in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, tcp

I have a situation where two "clients" connect to each other by performing simultaneously (TCP hole punching):

```js
// The socket already exist, and was connected to a rendez-vous server
// I re-use it with the same local port and address as it was using with the
// server, except now it's trying to contact its peer.
socket.connect({
    localAddress,
    localPort,
    port: peerAddresses.remoteAddress.port,
    host: peerAddresses.remoteAddress.host,
});
```

This works well. The socket is a TLSSocket that originally connected to a rendez-vous server.

After performing the hole-punching and connecting to the peer though, the encryption is lost (I think, based on what I saw with Wireshark).

Is there a way I can upgrade the connection between the peers to be encrypted?

I tried various flavors of:

```js
tls.connect({ socket: socket, secureContext: tls.createSecureContext(...) });

// or

new tls.TSLSocket(socket, { secureContext: ..., isServer: true /* just on one end */ })
```

on only one side of the connection (because my understanding is that TLS is asymmetrical, and you need a server and a client), and on both (because, why not...), but to no avail.

I'm starting to think I'm going to need to do the Diffie-Hellman key exchange manually, but I would really like to avoid that.

EDIT:
Here is one concrete example, with two client trying to connect to each other, and then upgrading:

```js
// clientA.js
const net = require('net');
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const localPort = 3018;
const peerPort = 3019;

const socket = net.createConnection({
  localPort: localPort,
  port: peerPort
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected!');

  const secureContext = tls.createSecureContext({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ca-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ca-cert.pem'),
  });

  const secureSocket = new tls.TLSSocket(socket, { isServer: true, secureContext });

  secureSocket.on('session', session => console.log('session', session));

  secureSocket.on('secureConnect', () => {
    console.log('securely connected!');
  });

  secureSocket.on('close', () => console.log('closing secure socket A'));
});

socket.on('error', (e) => { console.log(e); });

socket.on('close', () => {
  socket.connect({
    localPort: localPort,
    port: peerPort
  });
});
```

and

```js
// clientB.js
const net = require('net');
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const localPort = 3019;
const peerPort = 3018;

const socket = net.createConnection({
  localPort: localPort,
  port: peerPort
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected!');

  const secureSocket = new tls.TLSSocket(socket, { isServer: false });

  secureSocket.on('session', () => {
    console.log('session');
  });

  secureSocket.on('secureConnect', () => {
    console.log('securely connected!');
  });

  secureSocket.on('close', () => console.log('closing secure socket B'));
});

socket.on('error', (e) => { console.log(e); });

socket.on('close', () => {
  socket.connect({
    localPort: localPort,
    port: peerPort
  });
});
```

The "securely connected!" message never shows up, nor do the closing / session messages on the secure sockets.

I must say it does seem off to me to just instantiate a new TLS socket around the existing one - and indeed, it seemingly does nothing. I do get the `connected!` message, but no upgrade seem to happen.

If I were to call connect({ localPort: localPort, port: peerPort }) on the secureSocket, I would get EADDRINUSE, which makes sense to me.

I've also tried a scenario where I'd call `tls.connect({ socket: socket, secureContext: tls.createSecureContext(...) })` on both sides, but this also seems off because I cannot indicate which socket should behave as server.

Any tip welcome, I'm pretty much in the dark with what happens under the hood, I may need to dig into Node's internals at some point.

Comment: It looks you are doing things correctly to get the upgrade behavior you desire, but *...but to no avail...* is not a useful description of the problem. And yes, you must do this on both sides because both sides must immediately begin speaking the TLS protocol.

Comment: To no avail meaning: no error, nothing happens, the connection is still an unencrypted one.

Comment: But you're right, that's not very descriptive. When I'm home, I'll try to come up with a toy script to better illustrate what I'm trying to do, and how it fails. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see you sending any data in your example. Nothing happens until you send data from the client to the server.

Comment: Thank you! In the example above, I was expecting the secureConnect event to fire once the upgrade was completed. I later found in the doc: 

"The 'secureConnect' event is not emitted when a <tls.TLSSocket> is created using the new tls.TLSSocket() constructor."

I also did some writing in the socket and secureSocket in the "connect" event of the socket. That cause issues, and EADDRINUSE error appeared: once the "connect" even fires, we should not write anything in the socket. The upgrade to TLS requires a "clean pipe", according to my understanding. 

How do I credit you with the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user [President James K. Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77033245/how-to-upgrade-a-tcp-connection-to-tls-in-node-js?noredirect=1#comment135802458_77033245)!

Working code, to upgrade from regular TCP socket to TLS in Node.js:

```js
// clientA.js
const net = require('net');
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const localPort = 20001;
const peerPort = 20000;

const socket = net.createConnection({
  localPort: localPort,
  port: peerPort
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected!');

  // Do not call socket.write here! A "clean pipe" is needed to proceed to the upgrade

  const secureContext = tls.createSecureContext({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ca-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ca-cert.pem'),
  });

  // This constitutes the upgrade. One side needs to be a server, the other not.
  const secureSocket = new tls.TLSSocket(socket, { isServer: true, secureContext });

  // You can write here, but the client should initiate data sending, or the ping-pong won't start.
  // secureSocket.write('ping');

  secureSocket.on('keylog', (keylog) => {
    console.log('keylog', keylog.toString());
  });

  secureSocket.on('data', data => {
    console.log('received', data.toString());
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('sending ping');
      secureSocket.write('ping');
    }, 1000);
  });
});

socket.on('error', (e) => { console.log(e); });

socket.on('close', () => {
  socket.connect({
    localPort: localPort,
    port: peerPort
  });
});
```

and

```js
// clientB.js
const net = require('net');
const tls = require('tls');

const localPort = 20000;
const peerPort = 20001;

const socket = net.createConnection({
  localPort: localPort,
  port: peerPort
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected!');

  // Do not call socket.write here! A "clean pipe" is needed to proceed to the upgrade

  // This constitutes the upgrade.
  const secureSocket = new tls.TLSSocket(socket, { isServer: false });

  // This will start the ping-pong
  secureSocket.write('pong');

  secureSocket.on('keylog', (keylog) => {
    console.log('keylog', keylog.toString());
  });

  secureSocket.on('data', data => {
    console.log('received', data.toString());
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('sending pong');
      secureSocket.write('pong');
    }, 1000);
  });
});

socket.on('error', (e) => { console.log(e); });

socket.on('close', () => {
  socket.connect({
    localPort: localPort,
    port: peerPort
  });
});
```

`new tls.TLSSocket(socket, option)` does indeed perform an upgrade when one side is declared as server and provides a secureContext, and the other one is declared as a client.

The client should write some data first.

There is no need to call connect on the secureSocket - the socket is connected, doing so would result in an EADDRINUSE.

[The 'secureConnect' event is not emitted when a <tls.TLSSocket> is created using the new tls.TLSSocket() constructor.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/tls.html#event-secureconnect)

Thanks again!